# Linking cabalized Haskell package to C program (undefined reference linker error)

Tags: haskell, gcc, linker

My link command is:

```
gcc -O2 -m32 -o ParseInt.exe ParseInt.o hsbracket.o \
    -L../../dist/ia32/build -lffi -lHSarray-0.5.0.0-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHSbin-package-db-0.0.0.0-ghc7.8.3 -lHSbinary-0.7.1.0-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHSbytestring-0.10.4.0-ghc7.8.3 -lHSCabal-1.18.1.3-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHScontainers-0.5.5.1-ghc7.8.3 -lHSdeepseq-1.3.0.2-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHSdirectory-1.2.1.0-ghc7.8.3 -lHSfilepath-1.3.0.2-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHSghc-7.8.3-ghc7.8.3 -lHSghc-prim-0.3.1.0-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHShaskeline-0.7.1.2-ghc7.8.3 -lHShaskell2010-1.1.2.0-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHShaskell98-2.0.0.3-ghc7.8.3 -lHShoopl-3.10.0.1-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHShpc-0.6.0.1-ghc7.8.3 -lHSinteger-gmp-0.5.1.0-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHSold-locale-1.0.0.6-ghc7.8.3 -lHSold-time-1.1.0.2-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHSpads-haskell-1.1-ghc7.8.3 -lHSpretty-1.1.1.1-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHSprocess-1.2.0.0-ghc7.8.3 -lHSrts-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHSrts_debug-ghc7.8.3 -lHSrts_l-ghc7.8.3 -lHSrts_thr-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHSrts_thr_debug-ghc7.8.3 -lHSrts_thr_l-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHStemplate-haskell-2.9.0.0-ghc7.8.3 -lHSterminfo-0.4.0.0-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHStime-1.4.2-ghc7.8.3 -lHStransformers-0.3.0.0-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHSunix-2.7.0.1-ghc7.8.3 -lHSxhtml-3000.2.1-ghc7.8.3 \
    -lHSbase-4.7.0.1-ghc7.8.3  -Wl,-melf_i386
```

and I'm getting a bunch of errors like:

```
ParseInt.o: In function `main':
ParseInt.c:(.text.startup+0x16): undefined reference to `test'
../../dist/ia32/build/libHSrts-ghc7.8.3.so: undefined reference to `base_GHCziWord_W16zh_con_info'
../../dist/ia32/build/libHSrts-ghc7.8.3.so: undefined reference to `base_GHCziConcziSync_runSparks_closure'
../../dist/ia32/build/libHSrts-ghc7.8.3.so: undefined reference to `base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nonTermination_closure'
```

but the undefined references are defined in the base `.so` I linked against:

```
$ nm ../../dist/ia32/build/libHSbase-4.7.0.1-ghc7.8.3.so | grep base_GHCziWord_W16zh_con_info
26690:00550884 T base_GHCziWord_W16zh_con_info
$ nm ../../dist/ia32/build/libHSrts-ghc7.8.3.so | grep base_GHCziWord_W16zh_con_info
104:         U base_GHCziWord_W16zh_con_info
```

So why doesn't `libHSrts` see things defined in `libHSbase`? I was following the directions here: http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/so.xhtml, and had `ParseInt.exe` correctly linking at one point but then I added some libraries to the cabal package / wrote a bunch more Haskell code (`ParseInt.c` and `hsbracket.c` did not change).

I've read about linking order (https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/1542000), and `rts` is earlier in the link command than the `base` library it depends on, so I'm not sure why I'm getting undefined references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dumb and missed the obvious: try to fix the first error gcc printed.

I managed to get the `test` function removed from the exported modules in my cabal package. Upon re-building the cabal package with `test` added to the `.so`, all the linking errors went away.

Comment: Yes, though I'd accept another answer if someone can explain why the `rts` library is mentioned at all when the only error was in `pads-haskell`